# Django: Colocar una imagen especifica de la base de datos en un template

Tags: html5, django, django-models

Simplemente quiero hacer una galeria, donde se muestren las imagenes q almaceno en una base de datos, estoy usando una plantilla y no quiero usar un ciclo for como usualmente, para no alterar demasiado el codigo q ya tiene el archivo y porque no quiero poner todas las imagenes de dentro de la base de datos.

models:

```
class Arte(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=300)#auto_now_add permite guardar la fecha instantaneamente
    categorias = models.ManyToManyField(Etiquetas)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="Galeria", null=False, blank=False, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "Arte" 
        verbose_name_plural= "Artes"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

views:

```
def home(request):
    art=Arte.objects.all()
    return render(request, "AppGaleria/home.html", {"arte": art})
```

Segmento del template:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'AppGaleria/assets/img/portfolio/01-thumbnail.jpg' %}" alt="" />
```

Quiero cambiar el static del template para hacer referencia a una de las imagenes concretas q se encuentra en mi base de datos, q puedo controlar desde el administrador. Por ejemplo llamar a la imagen de nombre "LogoKorvo_2021.jpg" haciendo referencia a su nombre o id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya conoces el id de la imagen o puedes obtener el registro mediante un campo de la base de datos como un codename, lo mas sencillo es que lo obtengas desde la vista y lo pases al template así:

```
def home(request):
    art=Arte.objects.all()
    try:
        objeto_especifico = Arte.objects.get(pk=1) # Cambiar por el parametro deseado, pk, codename unico, etc
    except Arte.DoesNotExist:
        objeto_especifico = None
    return render(request, "AppGaleria/home.html", {"arte": art, 'objeto_especifico': objeto_especifico})
```

y en tu home.html

```
 {% if objeto_especifico %}

     {% if objeto_especifico.imagen %}

     <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ objeto_especifico.imagen.url }}" alt="" />

     {% endif %}

 {% endif %}
```